# Tevo tarantula Z- port burnt

Tags: z-axis, endstop, tevo-tarantula

I burnt the Z- port for the Z endstop. Can I use the Z+ port? I'm using Jim Brown's Marlin firmware.

Any help to change that is highly appreciated. I know nothing about code. Sorry for my ignorance. I'm new on this 3D printing universe.

Comment: burnt? Can you show a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [line 585](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/EasyConfig-2.0.x/config/default/Configuration.h#line585) of [Configuration.h](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/EasyConfig-2.0.x/config/default/Configuration.h) looks like this

```
// Almost all printers will be using one per axis. Probes will use one or more of the
// extra connectors. Leave undefined any used for non-endstop and non-probe purposes.
#define USE_XMIN_PLUG
#define USE_YMIN_PLUG
#define USE_ZMIN_PLUG
//#define USE_XMAX_PLUG
//#define USE_YMAX_PLUG
//#define USE_ZMAX_PLUG
```

That is to say, if the Maximum endstop ports/plugs aren't currently being used, then you could just redefine the pin used by `ZMIN` (Z-) to be that currently being used by the `ZMAX` (Z+), in the appropriate `pins_XXXX.h` file (contained within [MarlinTarantula/Marlin/src/pins/](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/tree/EasyConfig-2.0.x/Marlin/src/pins)), where `XXXX` depends upon which board you have (I don't know what board your printer has).

For example, if you have a RAMPS board then in [pins_RAMPS.h](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/EasyConfig-2.0.x/Marlin/src/pins/pins_RAMPS.h) at [line 79](https://github.com/JimBrown/MarlinTarantula/blob/EasyConfig-2.0.x/Marlin/src/pins/pins_RAMPS.h#line79) you would change

```
//
// Limit Switches
//
#define X_MIN_PIN           3
#ifndef X_MAX_PIN
  #define X_MAX_PIN         2
#endif
#define Y_MIN_PIN          14
#define Y_MAX_PIN          15
#define Z_MIN_PIN          18
#define Z_MAX_PIN          19
```

to become (note the change in the last two lines)

```
//
// Limit Switches
//
#define X_MIN_PIN           3
#ifndef X_MAX_PIN
  #define X_MAX_PIN         2
#endif
#define Y_MIN_PIN          14
#define Y_MAX_PIN          15
#define Z_MIN_PIN          19
#define Z_MAX_PIN          18
```

Then compile and reflash the firmware.

Obviously you would then plug the Z_MIN (Z-) wire from the endstop into the Z_MAX (Z+) port.